# node.js Error: Cannot find module '/Users/myname/app_name/server

Tags: node.js

I've tried starting three different node.js apps in the last week. While I initially get them to start, after I work on them a bit I get essentially the same error:

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/myname/app_name/server

I can't figure this out. In all three cases I am using express, but I'm not getting the "cannot find module 'express' " error that others had. It's like it doesn't see the whole root file, and I can't figure out why. Any ideas?

Here is the code:

```
`var express = require('express');

var app = express();

var handlebars = require('express-handlebars')
  .create({ defaultLayout:'main' });
app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

var fortuneCookies = [
edited for space,
];

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('home');
});
app.get('/about', function(req,res){
  var randomFortune = 
    fortuneCookies[Math.floor(Math.random() * fortuneCookies.length)];
  res.render('about', { fortune: randomFortune });
});

app.use(function(req, res, next){
  res.status(404);
  res.render('404');
});

app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
  console.error(err.stack);
  res.status(500);
  res.render('500');
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log( 'Express started on http://localhost:' + 
    app.get('port') + '; press Ctrl-C to terminate.' );
});
```

Comment: how did you install your express dependecy? `npm install express` or globally ?

Comment: can you post the code?

Comment: @kiro112 I installed express: sudo npm install --save express

Comment: The ' that appears before var express is not in the code. I must have hit it while I was pasting the code in.